# Using string.Replace(char, char) does not modify my string

Tags: c#

I have an input string `input` with value `0.003 m`.

I need to do a few things to it;

- Strip tags off of the end
- Replace all the dots(`.`) with commas(`,`)

This is what I have come up with :

```
try
{
    if (input == "")
    {
        throw new Exception("Cannot have an empty String")
    }

    if(input.Contains('.'))
    {
        input.Replace('.', ',');
    }

    char[] CharactersToStrip = { ' ', 'm', 'k', 'g' };
    string output = input.TrimEnd(CharactersToStrip);

    return output;
}
catch (Exception Exception)
{
    throw new Exception(Exception.Message);
}
```

Comment: Don't name your exception variable `Exception`. And better remove the try catch altogether since it has no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the replacement back to the input:

```
if (input.Contains('.'))
{
    input = input.Replace('.', ',');
}
```

Also, your `try-catch` is completely redundant.  All you're doing is destroying the stack information, so remove it completely.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this was in a debug environment to find the exception.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable, you have to reassign it: `input = input.Replace('.', ',');`

On the topic of exceptions, there are several remarks to give:

- Don't throw the general `Exception` but rather a subclass that is more descriptive
- Same as above but "catch" instead of "throw"
- Naming your variable `Exception` will cause a lot of confusion and violates naming conventions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Thanks for the tips, and concerns. I take them to heart. We all are learning and I thanks you for that.

Answer (score 1):

Sigh, been a long day. I need to give the replaced string a value, it does not fix within itself.

ie. `input = input.replace('.', ',');`

Thanks anyway.

Comment: SO, like talking to oneself, is sometimes all you need to locate a nagging problem :)